# Sharing image to other apps without saving it permanently in device storage in Android 10 and above

Tags: android, file, bitmap, uri, android-10.0

I need to share image from my app to another app, I've image bitmap and would need to save it temporarily so as to share it via share intent. For Android 10 and 11, I used below code. But the issue is, it create multiple copies each time I share the image(i.e saves it permanently on device). Is there a way I can save the image temporarily, or maybe in a location which is not visible to the user?
Please ping here, if I couldn't make myself clear.

```
    public Uri saveImageToGallery(Bitmap bitmap){
        OutputStream fos;
        Uri imageUri=null;
        final String timestamp= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        final String imageFileName= "/JPEG_YourContent_"+timestamp+ ".jpg";
        try {
            ContentResolver resolver=getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,imageFileName);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+ File.separator+"YourContent");

            imageUri=resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            fos=resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            Objects.requireNonNull(fos);


        }catch (Exception e){
//            Log.d("Exception in saving", e.toString());

        }
        return imageUri;
    }
```

Comment: Save the image to `getCacheDir()`, then use `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` method to get the `Uri` to use in your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

Comment: I have checked your solution, but it works only on Android 9 and below. I think it has something to do with content values and resolver in Android 10 and above.

Comment: "but it works only on Android 9 and below" -- no, it definitely works on Android 10 and above. For example, I use `FileProvider` [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v2.0/PdfProvider) for `ACTION_VIEW`, [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/tree/v2.0/T30-Share) for `ACTION_VIEW` and `ACTION_SEND`, and [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/CamChooser) for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.